# How do I select text between each occurrence of '-' from items in a table

Tags: sql-server

I need to pull the string between each `-` of each item number in a table.

Sample of item numbers:

```
T-111459-DK-CAS-DGE-2X8-RT-M
T-1114659-MON-SKL-WT-3X9-GLS
T-111469-DK-PNN-GLZ-3X9-LE-GLS
T-111469-ARL-RIP-M-2X8-DUCR
T-111469-ARS-MAD-L-1X8-NL
```

Here is what I would like to see using the first item number as an example:

- between '-'#1 and '-' #2 is (111459) as Vendor
- between '-'#2 and '-' #3 is (DK) as Line
- between '-'#3 and '-' #4 is (CAS) as Color

Answer (score 0):

I tried to hard-code it like:

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'T-1114659-MON-SKL-WT-3X9-GLS' --testing purpose

select substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1) as Vendor
,substring(replace(@str,concat('T-',substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1),'-'),''),1,charindex('-',replace(@str,concat('T-',substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1),'-'),''))-1) as Line
, substring(reverse(substring(reverse(@str),1,len(@str)- len(substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1)) - len(substring(replace(@str,concat('T-',substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1),'-'),''),1,charindex('-',replace(@str,concat('T-',substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1),'-'),''))-1))-4)),1,CHARINDEX('-',reverse(substring(reverse(@str),1,len(@str)- len(substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1)) - len(substring(replace(@str,concat('T-',substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1),'-'),''),1,charindex('-',replace(@str,concat('T-',substring(substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1,charindex('-',substring(@str,3, len(@str)-2),1)-1),'-'),''))-1))-4)))-1) as Color
```

Replace the @str with your column name accordingly.
Good Luck!

Comment: @TomT Could you please accept the answer if it helps you?